# Замена по регулярному выражению с условием "не перед x"

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно добавить в тексты знак ® перед названием компании, но там, где его пока нет.
Получается что-то вроде

```
$string = 'Это наша Компания®! Все что сделано в нашей компании, сделано компанией для нужд Компании. В компанию набирает сотрудников только наша компания';
echo preg_replace('/[^A-zА-яЁё]компании|компанией|компанию|компания[^\x{00AE}]/iu', '$0®', $string);
```

Исключение знака стоит только в последней форме, так как знак в тексте источника встречается только после "компания", но не после других форм.
Но такое выражение работает неправильно, оно захватывает другие знаки после "компания" (например, пробел) и не захватывает "компания" вообще, если слово стоит в конце строки.

Comment: `preg_replace('/\bкомпани\p{Ll}{1,2}\b(?!®)/iu', '$0®', $s)`? Приведите, пожалуйста, примеры строк и ожидаемые результаты.

Comment: Добавил пример строки в пост. Похоже, Ваш код делает именно то, что нужно, оформите его, пожалуйста, в виде ответа, чтобы я мог отметить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```
preg_replace('/\bкомпани\p{Ll}{1,3}\b(?!®)/iu', '$0®', $string)
```

См. [демо на PHP](https://3v4l.org/0Yu5H):

```
$string = 'Это наша Компания®! Все что сделано в нашей компании, сделано компанией для нужд Компании. В компанию набирает сотрудников только наша компания';
echo preg_replace('/\bкомпани\p{Ll}{1,3}\b(?!®)/iu', '$0®', $string);
// => Это наша Компания®! Все что сделано в нашей компании®, сделано компанией® для нужд Компании®. В компанию® набирает сотрудников только наша компания®
```

**Подробности**

- `\b` - граница слова
- `компани` - подстрока `компани`
- `\p{Ll}{1,3}` - одна, две или три строчных буквы (для поиска окончаний, от `-я` до `-ями`)
- `\b` - граница слова
- `(?!®)` - блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, сразу после текущей позиции не должно быть знака `®`.